# I can't load local variables for invokedynamic in ASM JAVA

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I have create a mini-logger for methods, and I use ASM. I need to determine by descriptor method parameters and print it.
But I have an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    ru/otus/TestLogging.calc(IFD)V @6: invokedynamic
  Reason:
    Type 'java/io/PrintStream' (current frame, stack[4]) is not assignable to double_2nd
  Current Frame:
    bci: @6
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'ru/otus/TestLogging', integer, float, double, double_2nd }
    stack: { 'ru/otus/TestLogging', float, double, double_2nd, 'java/io/PrintStream' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2a24 29b2 0007 ba00 3e00 00b6 0011 b200
    0000010: 071b 2429 ba00 0d00 00b6 0011 b1
```

This is code my Agent

```
public class Agent {

  public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

    inst.addTransformer(new ClassFileTransformer() {
        @Override
        public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader,
                                String className,
                                Class<?> classBeingRedefined,
                                ProtectionDomain protectionDomain,
                                byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                if(className.contains("ru/otus/")) {
                    return changeMethod(classfileBuffer, className);
                }
                return classfileBuffer;
        }
    });
  }

  private static byte[] changeMethod(byte[] originalClass, String className) {
      ClassReader reader = new ClassReader(originalClass);
      ClassWriter writer = new ClassWriter(reader, ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
      ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
      ClassVisitor visitor = new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, writer) {

          @Override
          public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor, String signature, String[] exceptions){
              System.out.println("visitMethod: access="+access+" name="+name+" desc="+descriptor+" signature="+signature+" exceptions="+exceptions);
              Method thisMethod = new Method(name, descriptor);

              MethodVisitor mv = new MethodAnnotationScanner(Opcodes.ASM5, super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions), thisMethod, className);
              return mv;
          }
      };

      reader.accept(visitor, Opcodes.ASM5);

      for(String methodName : list) {
          System.out.println(methodName);
      }

      byte[] finalClass = writer.toByteArray();

      if(className.contains("Test")) {
          try (OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("TestLogging.class")) {
              fos.write(finalClass);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }

      return writer.toByteArray();
  }

  static class MethodAnnotationScanner extends MethodVisitor {

      private Method thisMethod;
      private boolean isChangeMethod = false;
      private String className = null;
      private StringBuilder descriptor = new StringBuilder("(");

      public MethodAnnotationScanner(int api, MethodVisitor methodVisitor, Method thisMethod, String className) {
          super(api, methodVisitor);
          this.thisMethod = thisMethod;
          this.className = className;
      }

      @Override
      public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
          System.out.println("visitAnnotation: desc="+desc+" visible="+visible);
          if(desc.contains("ru/otus/annotations/Log")) {
              this.isChangeMethod = true;
              return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
          }
          this.isChangeMethod = false;
          return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
      }

      @Override
      public void visitCode() {
          if(this.isChangeMethod) {
              super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);
                  int i = 1;
                  for(Type arg : thisMethod.getArgumentTypes()) {
                      this.descriptor.append(arg.getDescriptor());
                      if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("J")) {
                          super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.LLOAD, i);
                          ++i;
                      } else if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("D")) {
                          super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.DLOAD, i);
                          ++i;
                      } else if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("F")) {
                          super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.FLOAD, i);
                      } else if(arg.getDescriptor().equals("I")) {
                          super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, i);
                      }
                      i++;
                  }


                  Handle handle = new Handle(
                          H_INVOKESTATIC,
                          Type.getInternalName(java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.class),
                          "makeConcatWithConstants",
                          MethodType.methodType(CallSite.class, MethodHandles.Lookup.class, String.class, MethodType.class, String.class, Object[].class).toMethodDescriptorString(),
                          false);
                  this.descriptor.append(")Ljava/lang/String;");
                  super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
                  super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("makeConcatWithConstants", this.descriptor.toString(), handle, "executed method: " + this.thisMethod.getName()  + ", param: \u0001".repeat(i));
                  super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
                  super.visitMaxs(0, 0);
              }

          if (mv != null) {
              super.visitCode();
          }
          super.visitEnd();
      }
   }
 }
```

I have two classes to reproduce this feature.
first - TestLogging
second - AutoLogger

In the first class I have a methods which need to logged,
In second it's start class contains method main.

[This is my project](https://github.com/Sparksss/otus_java_2020_03/tree/hw05-auto_logger)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks, simplified the code a bit, and add description about others class which are involved in process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pushing the arguments for the string concatenation before reading the field `System.out`, followed by attempting to perform the string concatenation. So the `invokedynamic` instruction intended to perform the string concatenation finds a mismatching `PrintStream` on the operand stack.

A simple fix is to change the instructions

```
super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("makeConcatWithConstants", this.descriptor.toString(), handle, "executed method: " + this.thisMethod.getName()  + ", param: \u0001".repeat(i));
super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
```

to

```
super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("makeConcatWithConstants", this.descriptor.toString(), handle, "executed method: " + this.thisMethod.getName()  + ", param: \u0001".repeat(i));
super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
super.visitInsn(Opcodes.SWAP);
super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
```

Or move the `GETSTATIC` before the code that will push the concat arguments, to the place where you perform the obsolete `super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, 0);`. Then, you don’t need `SWAP`.

But there are more problems with the code. You are counting the local variables while pushing the values, correctly considering `long` and `double` to take two variables, but then, you are using the same number in the `", param: \u0001".repeat(i)` expression, which will tell the `StringConcatFactory` that there were two values in case of `long` and `double`. You need to separate the counters. Also, you are not pushing reference type arguments, but since you are counting them and including them in the signature for the concat invocation, you must also push them to the operand stack.

Further, while not having an effect here, the `visitMaxs(0, 0)` call and the `visitEnd()` call are inappropriate. You are injecting at the beginning of the code and the other visit calls, which you will not intercept, will follow, including an automatically performed `visitMaxs` and `visitEnd`.

With all fixes, the code looks like

```
public void visitCode() {
    if(this.isChangeMethod) {
        super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
        int varIndex = 1, numArgs = 0;
        for(Type arg : thisMethod.getArgumentTypes()) {
            this.descriptor.append(arg.getDescriptor());
            if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("J")) {
                super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.LLOAD, varIndex);
                ++varIndex;
            } else if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("D")) {
                super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.DLOAD, varIndex);
                ++varIndex;
            } else if (arg.getDescriptor().equals("F")) {
                super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.FLOAD, varIndex);
            } else if(arg.getDescriptor().equals("I")) {
                super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, varIndex);
            } else {
                super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, varIndex);
            }
            varIndex++;
            numArgs++;
        }

        Handle handle = new Handle(
            H_INVOKESTATIC,
            Type.getInternalName(java.lang.invoke.StringConcatFactory.class),
            "makeConcatWithConstants",
            MethodType.methodType(CallSite.class, MethodHandles.Lookup.class, String.class, MethodType.class, String.class, Object[].class).toMethodDescriptorString(),
            false);
        this.descriptor.append(")Ljava/lang/String;");
        super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("makeConcatWithConstants", this.descriptor.toString(), handle, "executed method: " + this.thisMethod.getName()  + ", param: \u0001".repeat(numArgs));
        super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
    }
    super.visitCode();
}
```

As a side note, when you are pushing all arguments for the concatenation, you can simplify the descriptor construction, as the concat descriptor is almost identical to the method’s descriptor; you only have to replace the return type with `Ljava/lang/String;`.

You can do the entire operation without dealing with `Method` and `Type` objects, just using the two strings already passed to `visitMethod`.

```
@Override
public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String descriptor,
                                 String signature, String[] exceptions) {
    System.out.println("visitMethod: access="+access+" name="+name
        +" desc="+descriptor+" signature="+signature+" exceptions="+exceptions);
    MethodVisitor mv = new MethodAnnotationScanner(Opcodes.ASM5, name, descriptor,
        super.visitMethod(access, name, descriptor, signature, exceptions));
    return mv;
}
```

```
static class MethodAnnotationScanner extends MethodVisitor {

    private boolean isChangeMethod;
    private final String name, descriptor;

    public MethodAnnotationScanner(int api, String name,
                                   String methodDesciptor, MethodVisitor methodVisitor){
        super(api, methodVisitor);
        this.name = name;
        this.descriptor = methodDesciptor;
    }

    @Override
    public AnnotationVisitor visitAnnotation(String desc, boolean visible) {
        System.out.println("visitAnnotation: desc="+desc+" visible="+visible);
        if(desc.contains("ru/otus/annotations/Log")) {
            this.isChangeMethod = true;
            return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
        }
        this.isChangeMethod = false;
        return super.visitAnnotation(desc, visible);
    }

    @Override
    public void visitCode() {
        if(this.isChangeMethod) {
            super.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC,
                                 "java/lang/System", "out", "Ljava/io/PrintStream;");
            int varIndex = 1, numArgs = 0, p;
            for(p = 1; descriptor.charAt(p) != ')'; p++) {
                switch(descriptor.charAt(p)) {
                    case 'J':
                        super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.LLOAD, varIndex); ++varIndex; break;
                    case 'D':
                        super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.DLOAD, varIndex); ++varIndex; break;
                    case 'F': super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.FLOAD, varIndex); break;
                    case 'I': super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ILOAD, varIndex); break;
                    case 'L': super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, varIndex);
                        p = descriptor.indexOf(';', p);
                        break;
                    case '[': super.visitVarInsn(Opcodes.ALOAD, varIndex);
                        do {} while(descriptor.charAt(++p)=='[');
                        if(descriptor.charAt(p) == 'L') p = descriptor.indexOf(';', p);
                        break;
                    default: throw new IllegalStateException(descriptor);
                }
                varIndex++;
                numArgs++;
            }
            String ret = "Ljava/lang/String;";
            String concatSig = new StringBuilder(++p + ret.length())
                .append(descriptor, 0, p).append(ret).toString();

            Handle handle = new Handle(
                H_INVOKESTATIC,
                "java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory",
                "makeConcatWithConstants",
                MethodType.methodType(CallSite.class, MethodHandles.Lookup.class,
                    String.class, MethodType.class, String.class, Object[].class)
                    .toMethodDescriptorString(),
                false);
            super.visitInvokeDynamicInsn("makeConcatWithConstants", concatSig, handle,
                "executed method: " + name  + ", param: \u0001".repeat(numArgs));
            super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                "java/io/PrintStream", "println", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V", false);
        }
        super.visitCode();
    }
}
```